# Closing child from parent on another function

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I have a issue. I have a function A where I do a fork and then i wanna kill that fork after some instructions are done or on users request.
Something like this:

```
  int main{
    bool child_started =false;
    pid_t child_pid;
    while bool{
    //request user to make input
    //users makes a input.

    if(input == 1){
    functionA();
    }else if(input == 2 && child_started){
    //kill child
    //I tried kill(child_pid,SIGKILL); but it doesnt work
    }
```

And Function A

```
void functionA(){

child_pid= fork();
if(child_pid == 0){
child_started = true;
//instructions
exit(0); //I tried this but i get a zombie process
child_started = false;

}else if (child_pid<0){
//error handling
}
}
```

Any idea? I tried many ways but non succesfully.

thanks

On `functionA()` the instructions before `exit()` are time consuming. Let's assume that those instructions take 10min to execute. My point here is to kill the child process automatically after them, that's why the `exit()` is there. 
On main, the user can decide to kill the child before those 10min passes just inputing a 2.

------------------------------SOLVED----------------------------------------

If anybody comes with the same problem. DOnt waste your time reading the non-contributing answers. I solved it adding `wait()` after killing on the father.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you please elaborate? And of course please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. As for the zombie process, the parent need to [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for its child-processes to "reap" the zombies.

Comment: well, i think is pretty clear what "it doesnt work " means. Means that it doesnt work. I wanna kill a child from parent and what i tried does not work

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ You need to *tell us* how it's not working. In the body of the question itself. What is supposed to happen, what happens instead. Assuming or guessing makes for bad answers.

Comment: I also recommend you check what [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) returns, and if it return with a failure check `errno` to see what the error is.

Comment: So the problem was with the zombie process, not a problem with `kill` itself? If we don't know these details because you don't tell us them, how do you think we will be able to help you?  Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and most importantly [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

fork() returns 0 for child process and non-zero for parent process.here,you are terminating from child immediately after creating it(exit() terminate process it is not a return).when user try to kill using command line ,if child has already completed its execution then kill wont work here.

Comment: check my code again. Before the Exit() there are some instructions. Those instructions take some time and the user has the chance to imput a 2 to kkill the child intentionally. That's what im seeking.

Comment: user has the chance means its not  a defined behavior all the time, you are not sure whether child has done its execution already. try to see what kill returns to see if child is present or not when you are trying to kill it.

Comment: I check wether the child has finished, I just didnt add it here. I have a bool variable indicating the state of the child. I will add it on example code